# Animate layout shift in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-animations

I'm using angular animation and everything works well but I want to know if I can animate layout shift.

For example in this video, when that add task component get vanished, tasks section get snaped up immediately. Help me if I can animate it.

Check this Video --> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-c4S0L2EciXcQFvR2JClX06XhGTu5ioQ/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: It's looks like a router-animations: https://angular.io/guide/route-animations

Comment: @Eliseo He's just hiding/showing a component on click, the application is not routing.

Comment: @CurtisBlanchette, I saw a typical angular app with header and change the router from ,e.g. app/list to app/new, but, really I think that you're correct, simply is a component -the form- inside a div. The component is under a *ngIf, so a typical Angular animation using `:enter`and `:leave` (using `transform:'scale(0)'` and `transform:'scale(0)'`, and when the animation finish remove the div that contain the component makes the trick. the link about animations:https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#enter-and-leave-aliases

Comment: Yes, the issue is that the component is being removed from the DOM instantly after the animation has scaled the element to 0. Animating scale does not affect the bounding containers size, hence the "pop". transitioning the height property of the parent, the component can continue using :enter and :leave but the removal from the DOM will become seamless.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be animating the scale property of your component.

One suggestion might be instead to animate the height of the parent element.

This example is plain javascript/html/css but the concept carries over easily to an angular animation.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("animate-btn");
const outer = document.getElementById("outer");

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  outer.classList.toggle('collapsed');
});
```

```css
#outer {
  min-height: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
  transition: height .5s ease-out;
}
#outer.collapsed {
  height: 0;
}
#inner {
  background: pink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div>
      Content  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="animate-btn">Animate</button>
```